# Do I need a copy constructor if I'm using a vector to hold objects?

Tags: c++

Here is an example:

```
#ifndef CPP_PRACTICE_ACCOUNTS_H
#define CPP_PRACTICE_ACCOUNTS_H
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class Accounts
{
private:
    /* variables */
    std::string email,
                password,
                displayName,
                dateOfBirth;

    /* invariant */
    bool accountCreated;

    /* other */
    static int objectCount;

    /* private functions */
    void greeting() const;
    bool InvalidEmail();
    bool InvalidPassword();
    bool InvalidDOB();

public:
    Accounts();

    /* constructor used to create an account */
    Accounts(std::string email, std::string password, std::string dateOfBirth);

    /* throws error if invariant isn't established */
    class InvalidAccount{};

    /* getters */
    const std::string &getEmail() const;
    const std::string &getPassword() const;
    const std::string &getDisplayName() const;

    /* setters */
    void setDisplayName(const std::string &displayName);
    void setPassword(const std::string &password);

    /* other */
    static int getObjectCount();

};

#endif //CPP_PRACTICE_ACCOUNTS_H

//in main
int main()
{
    std::vector<Accounts> accounts;
    
    //create account objects and
    //push_back to the vector

    return 0;
}
```

Would I need to add a copy/move constructor and copy/move assignment operators to the Accounts class if I add them all to a vector? I ask because I because I know a vector copies by value but I'm wondering if everything would be copied properly. Thank you!

Comment: @cigien That is not a duplicate, this is about a type used inside a vector, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Oh, you're right, my bad.

Comment: Depends on the details of the member variables. (If you have pointers, you probably need a copy constructor (and others). If not, probably not.)

Comment: got it exactly what I needed to understand thank you.

Comment: are you asking if your type needs a copy/move constructor or whether you need to write one? The compiler will generate one for you if it can, whether it can and whether the default generated constructors are correct or not depends on the details of `Accounts`, please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I updated the code sorry. But yes I'm asking if I need to write one while used in conjunction with adding the objects to a vector.

Comment: depending on the behaviour of `objectCount` you can rely on the default copy/move contsructors as all your members are themselves copy/movable

Comment: @AlanBirtles got it thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until C++11 template parameter `T` in `std::vector<T>` had to meet `CopyAssignable` and `CopyConstructible` requirements.

After C++11 this was relaxed, depending on what operations are used on the vector.

For example in your case, if no operation on the vector is used where the copy is needed then no need for copy ctor.

Example ([Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73682332db61a354)):

```
#include <vector>

class Accounts
{
public:
    Accounts() = delete; // explicitely delete default constructor
    Accounts(const Accounts&) = delete; // explicetly delete copy ctor
};

//in main
int main()
{
    std::vector<Accounts> accounts;  // no need for copy or default ctor here, because no copy used and no object created
    // std::vector<Accounts> accounts(3); // error: now default constructor is needed
    
    //create account objects and
    //push_back to the vector - requires copy ctor
    // emplace_back - doesnt require copy ctor


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know a copy constructor was needed if I initialized the vector thank you!

Comment: Using `push_back` requires that the object be CopyConstructable.  If you use `emplace_back` instead, it is not required.

Comment: It still needs a move constructor for the realloc

Comment: @ChrisDodd push_back doesn't require that if you move the value in